# Operational amplifier as comparator - maximum input voltage

Tags: power-supply

Regarding the attached schematic and the IC2B op amp, what is the maximum input voltage allowed at the IN+ and IN- of IC2B ?

I read in the LM324 datasheet, that the differential input voltage is specified = +-32V. Also, in the same datasheet, in mentioned another parameter the Common-mode input voltage range which is equal to V+ - 1.5V.

I know that IC2B works as an comparator, when IN+ is higher than IN-, then the output will the Vcc, and when the IN- is higher than IN+, then the output will be 0V. 
Will the op amp IC2B work safely in this configuration ?
[image: Schematic]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are really two parts to this question.

1. Will it work without risking damage to IC2B
2. Will it function properly.

The voltage at both inputs will be within the power supply range so the +/-32V absolute maximum rating is easily satisfied, so it is not close to damage from differential input voltage. There is another constraint- input voltage must be between –0.3 to 32V. That also is satisfied since the output of IC2D will be within the range of 0-12V and likewise the output of the R6/R7/R8 divider will be well within that voltage range.

---

As to functionality- the voltage on the inverting input is determined by the resistors and pot. It can be set from nominally 9.8 to 10.8V. According to the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm324.pdf), for reliable operation as a comparator over the full temperature range at least one input has to be within the range of 0 to Vcc-2V or 0 to 10V nominally. So we cannot count on the inverting input being within this range, but it's close (which is bad).

[image]

The non-inverting input is driven by IC2D output which not sourcing any significant current, and we can see from figure 2 in the datasheet that it will typically sit at around Vcc - 1.2V, so that input is also outside the guaranteed working range.

[image]

So we can conclude that this circuit will not damage the amplifier in question, but it's a poor design that is not guaranteed to function properly at extremes of temperature (depending on the position of the trimpot!), but may well typically work on the bench (so odd and intermittent loss of functionality may be observed in the field).

Simply adding a single resistor from the non-inverting input to ground (a voltage divider) and changing the resistors values in the R6/R7/R8 chain to proportionally lower the voltage on the inverting input would that part of it reliable.

Comment: I'd suggest that the operating range specified in the data sheet might reflect reliable function as an op amp, and not as a comparator.  On the concerns side, there may well be lock-up issues and such.  On the other hand, conditions might well be relaxed for reliable comparator use.  There's no way to know except testing.  This is why I seek comfort by using comparators when I need a comparator.

Comment: @ScottSeidman To save time, I hand-waved a bit past why only one input has to be within the input common-mode range. One has to analyze the schematic to see that (which is provided in the datasheet, unlike most more modern op-amps and comparators). As to using op-amps as comparators, there are many circumstances where it's useful (to save money or for precision where speed is unimportant) but as you say perhaps best left for advanced design techniques (including ruthless cost-cutting). Some op-amps have back-to-back diodes across inputs etc.. The LM324 is an old friend with well known foibles.

Comment: By adding a resistor from non-inverting input to ground and changing the resistor values in the R6/R7/R8 chain, could result in power supply oscillation, or other "strange" problems of the power supply ?

Comment: I don’t think so, it only controls the LED.